# Как правильно внести данные в список?

Tags: python-3.6

подскажите пожалуйста: я новичок и столкнулся с проблемой:
У меня есть два разных класса, и при генерации объектов, каждый из них заполняет свой список.
Есть третий класс, который при создании объекта, должен брать переменную из одного из двух классов и добавляя к ней данные, записывать в 2 отдельных списка, для каждого класса отдельно. Проблема в том, что я сгенировал по 2 объекта каждого класса, но в один список записывается 1 запись - словарь, а во второй 3 записи. Должно бы по 2 записи на каждый список, не могу разобраться, в чем проблема, благодарю Вас.

```
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, limit):
        self.limit = limit
    pass
   

class Cash_Calculator(Calculator):
    c = [] 
    def __init__(self, a, b, limit=1000):
        self.a = int(a)
        self.b = int(b) 
        self.limit = limit
    def pluss(self):
        sum = self.a + self.b
        return Cash_Calculator.c.append(sum)

class Calories_Calculator(Calculator):
    b = [] 
    def __init__(self, a, b, limit=1000):
        self.a = int(a)
        self.b = int(b) 
        self.limit = limit
    def plus(self):
        sum = self.a + self.b
        return Calories_Calculator.b.append(sum)

class Records():
    calories = []
    cash = []
    d = dt.date.today()
    def __init__(self, amount=None, comment=None, date=None):
        self.amount = amount
        self.comment = input("Введите комментарий ")
        self.date = str(Records.d)
    def create_r(self):
        if len(Calories_Calculator.b) != 0:
          self.amount = str(Calories_Calculator.b[-1]) 
          a = {'amount=':self.amount for i in self.amount}
          b = {'comment=':self.comment for i in self.comment}
          c = {'date=':self.date for i in self.date}
          d = {**a, **b, **c}
          if len(Cash_Calculator.c) !=0:
            self.amount = str(Cash_Calculator.c[-1]) 
            a = {'amount=':self.amount for i in self.amount}
            b = {'comment=':self.comment for i in self.comment}
            c = {'date=':self.date for i in self.date}
            j = {**a, **b, **c}
            return Records.cash.append(j)
          return Records.calories.append(d)
F = Calories_Calculator(6, 6)
F.plus()
B = Records()
B.create_r()
C = Cash_Calculator(11, 5)
C.pluss()
B1 = Records()
B1.create_r()
F1 = Calories_Calculator(9, 6)
F1.plus()
B2 = Records()
B2.create_r()
C1 = Cash_Calculator(1, 4)
C1.pluss()
B3 = Records()
B3.create_r()
print(f'{Records.calories}')
print(f'{Records.cash}')
```

Comment: А какой смысл у таких конструкций: `{'amount=':self.amount for i in self.amount}`? Ключ словаря ведь одинаковый, итогом будет одна пара ключ-значение.

Comment: Вы знаете, была идея в том, что при создании объекта класса Records, я беру переменную из класса Cash_Calculator, потом добавляю к ней комментарий и добавляю дату. Если честно, я новичок, и нашел такое решение.

Comment: Честно говоря ваш код не очень понятно написан, попробуйте писать сначала небольшими кусками код и всё тестировать - добавляйте отладочную печать везде - просто `print` переменных делайте прямо в классе, везде делайте. И тогда у вас будет полный контроль над тем, что происходит. Так постепенно и разберётесь. Я боюсь если вам даже сейчас подскажут в чём проблема, это не сильно вас продвинет в понимании, что у вас в коде вообще происходит.

Comment: Спасибо, я так и делаю :) Декомпозицию, понятно, что нужно больше практики и опыта, буду работать, благодарю Вас.

Comment: А, ну если всё понимаете, тогда тесты ещё пишите, если ещё не. Если код писать модульно, а не большими простынями, и качественно покрывать тестами, то у вас будет полный контроль над тем, что у вас в коде происходит. Кстати, ещё меня смущает, что у вас много преобразований в `str`. Они обычно либо вообще не нужны (объект уже строка), либо нужны в очень специфических случаях, обратите на это внимание.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за поддержку.